# Remove spaces from the end of string

Tags: bash, shell

My problem is that I read a file and got array of strings, but each my string has spaces in the end, I need to remove it. Each line has different numbers of spaces. How can I do this?

Right now I can delete all spaces from each string, it looks like:

My code:

```
index=0
while read name; do
    get_user_group_from_file[$index]="${name//[[:space:]]/}"
    index=$(($index+1))
done < "${FILE}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is the parameter expansion code removes *all* spaces from a given input line. For e.g. see

```
str='line has spaces'
echo "${str//[[:space:]]/}"
linehasspaces
```

To remove only the last one, use a different construct with `bash` provides with `extglob`

```
str='line has 4 spaces last    '
echo "${str%%+([[:space:]])}"
```

So your whole script should look like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob

while read -r name; do
    get_user_group_from_file[$index]="${name%%+([[:space:]])}"
    index=$(($index+1))
done < "${FILE}"
```

Comment: @NikitaLitvinov : Click on the tick mark next to answer

Comment: `index=$(($index+1))` can be written as `((index++))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can output the file with removed trailing spaces like this:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' "$file"
```

example:

```
> echo "123   " > file
> echo "+$(cat file)+"
+123   +
> echo "+$(sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' file)+"
+123+
```

and another example:

```
> echo "123      " > file
> echo "+$(cat file)+"
+123      +
> sed -i -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//' file
> echo "+$(cat file)+"
+123+
```

or remove it from a string saved in a variable:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' <<<"$line"
```

example:

```
> string="alallal    ";
> string=$(sed 's/[ ]*$//' <<<"$string")
> echo "+${string}+"
+alallal+
```

The `[[:space:]]*` matches one or more whitespaces characters (tabs, spaces). If you want only spaces, replace that with just `[ ]*`. The `$` is used to indicate end of line.

To get count of lines in file, use `wc -l`:

```
index=$(wc -l < "$FILE")
```

Note that:

```
while read name
```

by iteself removes trailing and leading whitespace characters. Also allows backslash to escape characters. Use:

```
while IFS= read -r name
```

More about that topic can be found [here](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

To read a file into an array without trailing whitespaces, use:

```
mapfile -t get_user_group_from_file < <(sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' file)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, buy it doesn't do what I need. Could you please help me with my code?

Comment: `while read name` removes trailing newlines, don't know what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to change a line there

```
get_user_group_from_file[$index]="${name// *$/}"
```